# How to make the selenium webdriver script to wait for backend api request to return a response?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate an hybrid angularjs 2 (2.4.10) web application using selenium webdriver + Java + ngwebdriver.

Consider a simple case by  automating a basic login script.
 in login page, im using  sendkeys to fill in username and password fields and .click method to hit submit button and then im doing a assertion of homepage title. script runs smoothly and quits the driver instance.

but when script hits submit button, in backend an api call is made and responses arent recieved yet.

from frontend the Test Automation is achieved but the user login method hasnt returned response.

so i want my selenium webdriver script to wait for all backend api requests to return a response.and then move to next step? is it possible.

Comment: what is the next step after if login successfully, because for after successfully login which ever the activity comes we have to till that activity show up by adding implicit or explicit wait

Comment: Implicit waits is for elements to load up, so basically it makes the script to wait for elements to appear/to be visible in webpage and even explicit wait is for elements i.e. waiting for that element explicitly. but i'm concerned about the backend API calls.

Comment: if you know or not the selenium is used for UI Automation not for back end API's but if the response time is less then you can use wait for that much time to come response and wait for the next element isn't it..

Comment: i know that very well, but i was looking for something like running/initialize the  browsers/browser drivers  in network logging mode and capturing those requests automatically and to make my script to  wait for the API response and then the selenium webdriver to move to next step.  that is what im looking for.

Comment: I believe you're asking for waiting on browser's xhr requests, right? Once all "static" elements are loaded - the page's structure, layout, navigation, the app sends a request to the BE to get some data; when the xhr req receives response, that data is injected & visualized in the page - and you want for this process to finish before proceeding, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: @TodorMinakov : yes exactly.

Comment: I can't help you directly - I've been in this situation and had solved it with custom code in my app, feedback mechanism when all the date is in. But, if your application is based on jQuery, it (the library) keeps an internal counter of requests it has sent and is still waiting on a response. When the counter is at 0, the data is in.

Comment: And I've just reread your question, and saw its Angular; thus Shrini's answer looks like the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code to wait till the requests are fulfilled using ngWebDriver as below:

```
ngWebDriver.waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
```

Then use any explicit wait method for checking the visibility of the Element on the Landing page.

Comment: There is no need to use any kind of Implicit  wait or explicit wait when you are using
ngWebDriver.waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
This waitForAngularRequestToFinish() waits for all the components as well as requests. so No needed.

Comment: It depends on the implementation of angular requests and the page rendering. Some times the Page is not rendered as soon as the request is completed. Hence it is always better to have explicit waits before performing any action upon page load or navigation

Comment: In my angular application I have not used a single explicit wait as waitForAngularRequestToFinish() is performing all wait. As I have monitored the network too as the request is completed all the components are loaded.

Comment: @shrini thanks for the answer, i have already used this method but i can see lot of custom widgets used in applications like : fileupload, calendar. the responses of these kind of widgets are pretty late and in that time frame, test script would have moved to next step. so i was just thinking how to handle such custom implementations in my framework?

Comment: Try using explicit waits to wait till those elements are visible or clickable. This should  solve the wait problem.